# Background Program Not Looping

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that runs in the background looping to check if a page on the site has been changed. It works once and shows the message box but if I change it again it won't do anything.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.String
Imports System.IO
    Module Main
        Sub Main()
            While 1 = 1
                Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
                Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("http://noahcristinotesting.dx.am/file.txt")
                If reply.Contains("MsgBox") Then
                Dim Array() As String = reply.Split(":")
                MessageBox.Show(Array(2), Array(1))
                Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://noahcristinotesting.dx.am/noahcristinotesting.dx.am/file.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
                request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
                request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
                Dim path As String = "C:\test.txt"
                Dim createText As String = "completed"
                File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
                Dim fileftp() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\test.txt")
                Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                strz.Write(fileftp, 0, fileftp.Length)
                strz.Close()
                strz.Dispose()
            End If
            End While
        End Sub
    End Module
```

Comment: It works when running in studio but not when I run it from the exe.

Comment: When you step through this in the debugger, where/how specifically is it failing?  If it's only failing in a production setting, can you add some logging to narrow down the problem?

Comment: @David When the message box pops up the process disappears but when I click OK I comes back for 2 seconds then disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure at this moment what is causing it to crash when run outside of the IDE, but try trapping exceptions that are being thrown in the loop. I imagine there's an exception happening, cratering your app. The below catch block is by no means production ready, normally you want to catch specific exceptions in order to handle them effectively, but this is a cheap way to see if an exception is being thrown and what it is at runtime.

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        While 1 = 1
            Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
            Dim reply As String = client.DownloadString("http://noahcristinotesting.dx.am/file.txt")
            If reply.Contains("MsgBox") Then
                Dim Array() As String = reply.Split(":")
                MessageBox.Show(Array(2), Array(1))
                Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://noahcristinotesting.dx.am/noahcristinotesting.dx.am/file.txt"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
                request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
                request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
                Dim path As String = "C:\test.txt"
                Dim createText As String = "completed"
                File.WriteAllText(path, createText)
                Dim fileftp() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\test.txt")
                Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
                strz.Write(fileftp, 0, fileftp.Length)
                strz.Close()
                strz.Dispose()
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could check your event viewer in windows to see if a .net application exception is being logged. Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application

Comment: I checked event viewer and It turns out I just need to run it as administrator... -_-